# Uso de excepciones personalizadas

Tags: java, poo, excepciones

tengo un problema con las excepciones; tengo que hacer un traductor español-inglés básico, tengo dos **ArrayList**, uno para las *palabras en español* y otro para *palabras en inglés*. Uno de los métodos es traducir del español, es el siguiente:

```
/**
     * Se le pasa por parametros la palabra que queremos traducir al ingles.
     * @param espanol
     * @throws PalabraNoEncontradaException 
     */
    public void traducirEspanolIngles(String espanol) throws PalabraNoEncontradaException {
        //realiza una busqueda por el array palabrasespanol
        for(int buscar=0; buscar<palabrasespanol.size(); buscar++) {

        if(palabrasespanol.get(buscar).equals(espanol)) {
            System.out.println("Palabra español: "+espanol);
            System.out.println("Palabra ingles: "+palabrasingles.get(buscar));

        } else throw new PalabraNoEncontradaException();
    }       
}
```

Debo usar **excepciones personalizadas**, que es ahí donde me da el fallo. La excepción es esta:

```
public class PalabraNoEncontradaException extends Exception {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public PalabraNoEncontradaException() {
    System.err.println("La palabra que busca no existe o tiene error de sintaxis.");
}
}
```

A la hora de ejecutar el código, **se lanza siempre la excepción**, aunque el método funcione correctamente. ¿Cómo puedo evitar que se lance continuamente? **Ya he probado con try/catch.**

Comment: Lanzas la excepción en un *for*, cada vez que la palabra que estás iterando no coincide con la que buscas. Deberías lanzar la excepción solo si **ninguna de las palabras sobre las que has iterado es la que buscas**. Y por supuesto, el problema no tiene nada que ver con el uso de excepciones "personalizadas".

Comment: @SJuan76 Efectivamente, era ese fallo tan tonto. Ya lo he probado y funciona a la perfección.